# How to sort a vector of vectors by sum?

Tags: rust

I have `ks: Vec<(Vec<u64>, U)>` that I would like to sort by the tuple's 1st element's sum. How do I do that?

I tried this

```rust
ks.sort_by_key(|k| k.0.iter().sum());
```

But this gives me the error message

```
type annotations needed
cannot infer type for type parameter `K` declared on the associated function `sort_by_key` (rustc E0282)
: consider specifying the type argument in the method call: `::<S>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the return type of the closure that you are sorting after. Changing your code to this will work:

```rust
ks.sort_by_cached_key::<u64, _>(|k| k.0.iter().sum());
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `sort_by_cached_key` instead of `sort_by_key` as the sum remains stable while sorting and would otherwise get recomputed on every pairwise comparison.